# Meaning of "." as path for `java.io.File`

Tags: scala

Learning Scala and very excited!!

I am learning control structures at the moment. Came across the following 2 lines of code to print out all the list of files in a dictory.

```
val filesHere = (new java.io.File(".")).listFiles

for (file <- filesHere)
    println(file)
```

can someone explain what is "." mean in first line of code
Thanks much

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html  It's the constructor argument to file, a file path.

Comment: In some/most filesystems `.` is the current directory.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I edited your question title to make it refer to your actual problem. As has been mentioned above, most file-systems treat `.` as the current directory. `..` is the parents directory. [See this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)).

Comment: Thank you so much Alex and Jasper